# Is this possible to use Sheets API post endpoint with UrlFetchApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, urlfetch

I'm trying to append data to a spreadsheet.

I use `UrlFetchApp` to `GET` values but is it possible to `POST` values, for example, to append rows to a spreadsheet?

Here is my code so far

```
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var options = {
  "headers": {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
   },
  "method": "POST",
  "Content-type" : "application/json",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(values) //stringify a 2D array of data
}

var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/RangeName:append?insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS", options);
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using the advanced Sheets service?

Comment: @TheMaster `UrlFetchApp` is faster

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is useful information, in my environment, I have obtained that the process costs of reading and writing using UrlFetchApp make the costs of Advanced Google Services reduce by about 6 % and 4 %, respectively. You can see the experimental data at here. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4#Appendix

Comment: Jsmith, I see. Still it's just 5% cost reduction right?  @Tanaike  Thank you for the information. It's really useful.

Comment: @TheMaster Yes. In my environment, I obtained such result. As another advantage, I think that in the case that I create a library using Sheets API, when it uses Sheets API with UrlFetchApp instead of Advanced Google Services, users can use the library by enabling Sheets API at only API console. By this, the usability becomes a bit high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use Sheets API post URLs with UrlFetchApp. So how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Please use `valueInputOption` to the query parameter.

  - In your endpoint, I think that an error of `valueInputOption' is required but not specified` occurs.
- When you want to use `Content-type`, please add it to the headers.

  - If you want to use the content type outside of the headers, please use `contentType: "application/json"`.

#### Modified script:

```
// sample values
var values = {"values":[["a1","b1","c1"],["a2","b2","c2"]]};
var spreadsheetId = "### spreadsheetId ###";
var RangeName = "### RangeName ###";

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var options = {
  "headers": {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token,
       "Content-type": "application/json", // Modified
   },
  "method": "POST",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(values) //stringify a 2D array of data
}
var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheetId + "/values/" + RangeName + ":append?insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED"; // Modified
var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

#### Note:

- Before you run this script, please confirm whether Sheets API is enabled at API console.

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thank you again @Tanaike for the moment I only upvote but I will try and mark it as answer if that works. Thanks again.

Comment: @JSmith Thank you for replying. If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked one thing you can add though is that I had to modify the manifest file with this ` "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],` . What do you think does it make sense. Many thanks in advance

Comment: @JSmith Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About adding scopes, when the scopes is added to Manifests, it makes the script editor automatically not be able to detect the scopes from the script. So in your case, for example, how about automatically adding the scope of ``spreadsheets`` by putting a comment of ``// SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()``. ``script.external_request`` is added by using ``UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)``. If you don't want to add other scopes, please use Manifests. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: Well kind of. from what I understand you suggest I add the spreadsheet read/write scope by using commented `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`. adding "oAuthScope" in manifest requires I add manually all desired scopes Am I correct?

Comment: @JSmith Yes. When scopes are set to Manifests, the auto detection of script editor is turned off. So when the methods using other scopes is used in the script, the error related to the scopes occurs. I think that for example, this information might be useful. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/23ddf599a4155b66f1029978bba8153b